# Cracked and sunk concrete - Lift or fill?

Tags: concrete, foundation, waterproofing, foam

I have a shed that is 90+ years old. The shed structure itself is in great condition (someone actually replaced a bunch of the framing), however, the slab is a mess. It was built before rebar was used and has cracked extensively in the middle and sunk on the edges.

This results in ponding rain water to come in from the sides bringing in dirt, leaves and of course, humidity.

The long term plan is to redo the slab, however in the short term, I am considering options to keep water and dirt out. One is to inject expansion foam and try to raise the concrete on the edges. This would level the floor a little and raise the slab sill above the ground level. Given the state and the number of cracks on the foundation, I'm not sure if trying to raise it is a viable option; awaiting some quotes on this.

Another option is to use expansion foam to create a barrier stopping water from coming in. This would be the easiest option, although it does not address the issue that the bottom plate is below ground level and will continue to absorb water.

Given that water ingress is a problem right now, option 2 doesn't appear to make things worse. I am looking to put a vent to reduce any moisture accumulation.

Is option 2 a viable approach for the short term to seal my shed from the elements?

The concrete slab has sunk and the structure has slid off it slightly. The second picture is the extent of the cracking in the middle. The horizontal displacement is about 1.5-2 inches resulting in the edge having 4-5 inches of vertical space.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why is a big (and expensive) foam worm better than some exterior grade correction? Maybe a photo or two would clarify. I'm not seeing the reason for your unorthodox approach.

Comment: Post updated with additional info

Comment: Unless my eye deceives me that wall is displaced by at least 5 inches. Not "slightly". I think your attention is misplaced.

Comment: It isn't quite that much. It is about 1.5 to 2 inches of horizontal displacement. Vertically, it is 4-5 inches as this side is not supported by the slab for approx 4 feet. Added clarification to the OP as well.

Comment: Are you sure? Looks to me like all those studs at the corner should be over the bottom plate, and the wall coming toward us should be over the raised portion of the slab. Unless it's lens distortion, you can see it in the acute angle between the studs and the plate.